# CSS - Differentiate between drop down select and list box select

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a way using CSS to target drop down (size='1') and list box (size='[2+]')  elements seperatly other than by using classes or ids?

Cross browser and IE6 :( compatibilty would be ideal.

Thanks

**EDIT - Solution (IE 7 + with !DOCTYPE)** Thanks To [SW4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404335/sw4)

```
select{
    /*All select elements (Drop downs and Lists)*/
}

select[size]{
    /*All select elements with size specified (Typically just lists unless you specify a select with size='1')*/
}

select[size='1']{
    /*All select elements with size='1', does not include elements where size is not specified*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is a [**CSS attribute selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), so your rule could be e.g:

```
select{
   /* everything with a size > 1 */
}
select[size=1]{
   /* everything with a size attribute === 1 */
}
```

With that said, attribute selectors are part of the CSS3 module so [**not supported natively by IE6**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx#attributeselectors), you will need a 3rd party compatibility library such as [**selectivizr**](http://selectivizr.com/) if you wish to use them.

With that in mind, if you are able- why not go down the class route and add a class to each element with `size=1` to style them as an exception?

Alternatively, and this isn't CSS specifically but jQuery 1.x (which supports IE6) has [**attribute selectors**](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/), you could leverage this to identify qualifying elements then apply a CSS class to these directly, e.g.:

```
$('select[size=1]').addClass('css-class');
```

Comment: Thanks this looks to be the best option, IE6 compatibility is desirable but if it looks a bit odd on IE6 it won't matter as long as its still functional.

Comment: @apc you want IE6 support? Seriously?

Comment: I guess you mistyped the selector in the example for jQuery ... shouldn't it be `$('select[size=1]')`? you missed that closing square bracket ...

Comment: I dont 'want' to. This is mainly for Intranet sites. Our baseline for suppoted systems is Server 2005, Windows XP and IE6, we still have a few customers using server 2003 and Windows ME! .

Comment: Its worth noting that the attribute selector only works if you specify size='1' on the element it dosn't work with the default value for the attribute. You can target elements with the size attribute (regardless of value) by just using select[size]